# /usr/X11R6 is missing in Ubuntu 12.04TLS

Tags: 12.04

I have upgraded my Ubuntu from 10.10 to 12.04 LTS, but the GUI is no more working. In CLI mode, it is saying that /usr/X11R6 is missing.

Can you please help me on this? How can i recover X11R6??

Thank you for your prompt response.